# filtering value based on selectlist value

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a select list which lest the user select a sales rep Id. Based on that I want to display the Rep name in an outputtext. following is my controller code:

```
public  String repname {
        get {
           Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;               
           String Results = [Select Name
                             From User 
                             where Sales_Rep__c =: RepId limit 1];
           return Results ;
        }
        set;
}
```

RepId here is the output of selectlist. 
This code gives error: **Illegal assignment from LIST to String**.. How can I possibly select the repname here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APEX `Select` always return a `List`, so here's what you need to do:

```
List<User> Results = [Select Name
                      From User 
                      Where Sales_Rep__c =: RepId limit 1];
// Do some sanity check if necessary to make sure Results.size() is 1
return Results.get(0).Name;
```

Comment: @ Mingyu. thanks for the response but with this code, it gives an error that **Illegal assignment from LIST<User> to LIST<String>**    I also tried changing it to `LIST<User> Results =` but then the return statement gives an error

Comment: Select statements don't always return a list, they can return a singleton object too, and with dot notation you can extract a field from a SOQL in a single line.

Comment: Using List<User> would work in this scenario, but then instead of "returning" the variable results, you would have to do something like return Results.get(0).name;

Comment: @Robin, I updated my answer.

Comment: by the way a small help further. the rep name that gets returned is not formatted. I want First letter of both first name and last name to be capital and rest all letters to be small..is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: That sounds like a different question.  You might want to start another question, and show us what you see now, and what you would like to see after the fix.  Also example helps.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you can just add `.name` to the end of your query like so:

```
public  String repname {
   get {
   Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;               
   String Results = [Select Name From User where Sales_Rep__c =: RepId limit 1].name;
   return Results ;
  }
  set;
}
```

And the query will return a string for you into Results.

Comment: thanks Simon. This worked too. I guess both answers are slightly different ways of doing the same thing. Thanks again for the help..

Comment: by the way a small help further. the rep name that gets returned is not formatted. I want First letter of both first name and last name to be capital and rest all letters to be small..is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: there is a code snippet in the middle of this discussion that might be of use to you: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008zVUIAY it takes a string, breaks it up over spaces, and then capitalises the first letter of each block (loosely). You should be able to implement this and then call it on your returned value in the controller. Looks like it might need a tweak or two though.

Answer (score 1):

All you need:

```
public  String repName {
  get {
    return [Select Name From User where Sales_Rep__c = :repId limit 1].Name;
  }
  set;
}
```

Formatting name (This assumes that there are at least 2 characters in both FirstName and LastName):

```
public String repName
{
  get
  {
    User rep = [SELECT FirstName, Lastname FROM User WHERE Sales_Rep__c = :repId LIMIT 1];
    return rep.FirstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + rep.FirstName.subString(1).toLowerCase() + ' ' + rep.LastName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + rep.LastName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  } set;
}
```

Comment: If you tell your VF page to only display this field if repId is populated, you won't need any checks in your apex.

Comment: thanks dphil...this works perfectly. However, the rep name is not formatted. Is there a way to convert the 1st letter of first name and last name to capital and rest all in lower case?

Comment: Well, this brings back the name as entered.  If you are trying to format it that way, what happens when a last name is like McDonald?  This can be a valid capitalization for a last name, but will make the last name incorrect if you do your formatting.  The best bet is to make sure you enter the Users with the correct capitalization in names to begin with.  If you still want to format it though, I can edit my answer.

Comment: yes please..the data is already residing in the system and can not be changed. Also the data gets updated through multiple sources so very difficult to monitor all. I agree with the example of McDonald but that would be one of very few. It will help a great lot if you can help convert the 1st letter to capital for both first and last name..

Comment: Updated to add the second request.

Comment: Ohh I see what you did here..concatenating FN and LN..but in my data I dont have FN and LN as separate variables..its just one variable called Name which holds the entire name of the rep..

Comment: In your data, you should have FN and LN as separate variables.  The Name field is populated from the FirstName and LastName variables.  If they don't have any values, that means the Name field doesn't either.